# Javascript error: TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'event.target') on safari

Tags: javascript

I have difficulty on integrating my JavaScript syntax. My code is working on Internet Explorer (IE). However, I encountered a JavaScript error when running it on Safari.

This is my test code:

```
document.onmouseup = function hideaddrspopup () {   
    if (event.srcElement.id != 'fieldName') {   
        alert(event.srcElement.id);
    }
}
```

I tried something like:

```
document.onmouseup = function hideaddrspopup() {    
    if (event.srcElement.id != 'fieldName' || event.target.id != 'fieldName') { 
        alert(event.srcElement.id);
        alert(event.target.id);
    }
}
```

But still an error is appearing on the console:

> 'TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'event.target')'

I am aware that `event.scrElement` is only working in IE. How to make it work on the other browsers?

Comment: event.srcElement was an IE invention. To be compatible with IE < 9, use `even.target || event.srcElement`.

Answer (score 4):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/srcElement):

> This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between implementations and the behavior may change in the future.

Event.srcElement is a proprietary alias for the standard Event.target property. It is specific to old versions of Microsoft Internet Explorer.

So just avoid using event.srcElement instead you should use [event.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target).

Comment: event.srcElement isn't really an alias, it was an IE property that was copied by some other browsers for compatibility.

Comment: @RobG Absolutely agree with you. But currently we can just say as an alias.

Answer (score 2):

As Bhojendra mentioned don't use `srcElement`. Check for object null or not before accessing `id` or `target` property as below.

```
document.onmouseup = function hideaddrspopup () 
{   

if (e && e.target && e.target.id!='fieldName')
  {   
    alert(e.target.id);
  }
else if(e && e.srcElement && e.srcElement.id!='fieldName')
  {
    alert(e.srcElement.id);
  }
}
```

Updated with `else if` to support older IE browser. `target` should support it too but you could test without else part if it is necessary or not.

Comment: Consider `(event.target || event.srcElement).id`. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the event variable in your function

```
document.onmouseup = function hideaddrspopup (event) 
{   

   if (event.srcElement.id != 'fieldName' || event.target.id != 'fieldName')
   {   
     alert(event.srcElement.id);
     alert(event.target.id);
   }
}
```

Comment: That should be the other way around, since `event.srcElement` may return *undefined* (per the OP) so attempting to access its *id* property will throw an error. And in IE<9 `event.target` will return *undefined* so `(event.target || event.srcElement).id` may suit better.