# srcElement is not working in other browsers

Tags: javascript

I have an error on javascipt syntax using scrElement. I used this code.

```
function SetaTestfunction(obj){
    if (obj != null)
        el = obj;
    else
        el=event.srcElement;

    //code follows..
}
```

An error 'TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'event.srcElement')' on this line: event.srcElement

Also I tried to test it using this line of code.

```
function SetaTestfunction(obj) {
    alert(event.srcElement);
    alert(event.target);
    //code follows..
}
```

But no luck.

The code is working on IE and Chrome however, it doesn't work on Safari. Can somebody tell me what should I use?

Answer (score 0):

[Reniel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2865127/reniel-ramos-salvador) has answered the for the same in your previous question:

[javascript-error-typeerror-null-is-not-an-object-evaluating-event-target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35146784/javascript-error-typeerror-null-is-not-an-object-evaluating-event-target) If you faced any issue while implementing this. please post the error and code you have tried.

```
document.onmouseup = function hideaddrspopup (event) 
{
  if (event.srcElement.id != 'fieldName' || event.target.id != 'fieldName')
   {   
     alert(event.srcElement.id);
     alert(event.target.id);
   }
}
```